# Include Jade chunk from a parent directory

Tags: node.js, pug

I would like to make a Jade file `include.jade` available as an include to other Jade files `file.jade`, `layout.jade` in this directory structure:

```
layouts/layout.jade
documents/file.jade
includes/include.jade
```

The following are not working:

```
include ../includes/include.jade
include /includes/include.jade
include "../includes/include.jade"
```

Is there a way to specify the parent folder in the Jade `include` directive?
Or is there another way to achieve inclusion in files within different directories?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `.jade` extension. Try:

```
include ../includes/include
```